# Opening adt, adi and adm files

Tags: database, migration, sybase

I am developing a web application and I have a folder containing a bunch of files with .adm , .adi and .adt and .bak extensions.I want to be able to read this data and convert put it in mysql db.
I have figured that these are files stored by sybase in its proprietary format. I have opening with sybase advantage server but the folder does not have a .db file. 
I am really trying hard to just read this data but am not able to. It'd be a great help if you can give me some direction.

Answer (score 10):

On one very old server, i found the files, and i could open it with "Advantage Data Architect" software.
Maybe helps someone.

Comment: Helped me out :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really old post but some people (like me) might get here by Googling because they have an issue like mine. If you just open the file in notepad you MIGHT be able to read some of the data. My issue was with Medisoft version 17. A client of mine was transferring computers and we needed the registration code that is generated for the upgrade serial number. (It's in rgnpds.adt. look for the serial number and it should be the next "string" of characters). I just opened it up in notepad and the information that would normally be displayed to the user if they generated a report was readable in notepad. Hope this helps someone even if I am too late for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The better way to open the ADT file will be with Advantage Data Architect,
the other extensions are the index and memo files.
Thanks